# How to integrate wordpress blog into a custom Single page app website hosted on AWS using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, single-page-application

I have a custom website that is hosted on AWS managed using Elastic BeanStalk. The web app is built using ANgularJS framework. I have a separate blog hosted on wordpress. I would like to migrate and integrate this blog into existing website. Has anyone had experience with this? If so can i get some pointers on how to proceeed here.

Example. my custom website is mywebsite.com 
Current wordpress blog is myblog.com
I want to create mywebsite.com/blog and have all my wordpress blog content integrated into mywebsite.com/blog

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS CloudFront for this. Include the Blog and the Angular App as two origins and add behaviors accordingly to route. Map your domain name to AWS CloudFront.

e.g Create a behavior for /blogpost to point to Wordpress origin. mywebsite.com/blogpost -> WordpressDNS/blogpost

If you have URL rewrite requirement, use Edge Lambda to code the URL rewrite logic.

For more details in setting up Wordpress behind CloudFront refer [this](http://www.danneh.org/2015/04/setting-wordpress-amazon-cloudfront/) blog post. In addition you will need to install a Wordpress Plugin to avoid Mixed Content issues (If you setup SSL for your website).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! i will look into the blog post!

Comment: @locularsdev If you have plugins like woocommerce, putting CloudFront could affect the functionality. make sure you don't have any full paths hard coded in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks @Ashan for the heads up. I dont have much experience on cloudfront so i will have to do some reading up before. Would  this behavior act more like a traditional redirect?

Comment: @locularsdev It will work more like setting up a proxy in front of Wordpress. Unlike redirect, users won't see any url changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options I can think of:

A: You could simply do a wordpress installation in the blog directory, of course needing php/mysql running on your environment.

B: You could install wordpress and use it as a back end and use Angular as your front end so that it easily integrates with your current app. The front end would consume data from the WP API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! for Option B: wouldnt that also require the mysql db to be running on the environment? And would there be any implications of migrating the existing content to this setup? Are there any articles pointing to this setup? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes it would.  You pretty much have to use mysql with Wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Installation

WordPress requires access to a MySQL database or MariaDB database to store information. So you need a database.

Comment: The one potential challenge i see could be that since we are using Elastic bean stalk and a node.js container, in not sure how to add php support to that..since a php container is would be a separate app instance. Do you have any experience regarding this?